# help with (simple?) inequality

Tags: inequality

Let $x\in(0,1)$ be any and let $0<a<b<\frac{1}{2}$, I need to show that $$1-(1-x^a)(1-x^{1-a})>1-(1-x^b)(1-x^{1-b}).$$ Any suggestions? References? In practice I need to solve a more general case where I have $1-\prod_{i=1}^I (1-x^{a_i})$ and the $a_i$ are more spread-out than the $b_i$ and $\sum a_i =\sum b_i =1$ but I think if someone can help with the small case the larger one should be easy. Thanks for any hints, links, suggestions, etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**  $\quad$ In general, you could use [Karamata's inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karamata%27s_inequality), applied for the concave function $f(t) = \log(1-x^t)$, noting that $(a_i) \succ (b_i)$ if $a_i$ are more "spread out". So

$$\sum f(b_i) \ge \sum f(a_i) \implies \prod(1-x^{b_i}) \ge \prod(1-x^{a_i}) \\ 
\implies 1- \prod(1-x^{a_i}) \ge 1-\prod(1-x^{b_i})$$

Comment: I knew about Jensen's. Karamata's is new to me. It is going to very useful in the future. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The equivalent inequality is: $x^{1-b} + x^b < x^{1-a} + x^a$. Fix $x \in (0, 1)$ and consider $f(t) = x^{1-t} + x^t$ on $t \in(0, \frac{1}{2})$. We have: $f'(t) = lnx\cdot (x^t - x^{1-t}) < 0$ for $x \in (0,1)$. Thus $f(b) < f(a)$ when $0 < a < b < \frac{1}{2}$.